# Is there a better way to point to a sub graph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'd like to point to a sub graph where the line stops on the edge.
From what I understand I can select any of the nodes in the sub graph.
Is there a way to create an invisible node that you can point to?

```
 digraph G {
    compound=true;
    subgraph cluster_a{ 
        label="node1";
        node1;
    }

    node2->node1 [lhead=cluster_a];
 }
```

Ideally node1 should not be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use `style=invis`:

```
node1 [style=invis];
```

Comment: I have tried that, it does make the node invisible, but it still takes up space. I'ave also tried to set the height and width to 0.0 with the same results.

Comment: Try using `shape=none, label=""` to use less space. Or, if that doesn't work, you may abandon the subgraph's label and display the node's label instead.